# creating xml from multiple sql tables

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008

I tried to create a xml file from 3 sql tables as below

```
SELECT * 
FROM approval approval,
diag diag,
ser ser
where approval.id = diag.id
and approval.id = ser.id
FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS,
root('Head')
```

i got the o/p as below

```
<Head>
  <approval>
     .........
  <diag>
     ........
  <ser>
    ........
  </ser>
  </diag>
 </approval>
<Head>
```

My needed o/p is.

```
 <Head>
      <approval>
         .........
      <diag>
         ........
      </diag>
      <ser>
        ........
      </ser>
     </approval>
    <Head>
```

how to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer.

```
SELECT approval.*,
(select diag.*
from diag diag 
where approval.id =diag.id
FOR XML PATH('diag'), TYPE
),
(select ser.*
from ser ser
where approval.id =ser.id
FOR XML PATH('ser'), TYPE
)
FROM approval approval,
where approval.id = 1
FOR XML PATH, ELEMENTS,
root('Head')
```

Comment: Great that you found your solution! One tiny hint: You should use `FOR XML PATH`, better than `AUTO` or any other way. And please set the acceptance check  to your own answer to show to other users that this question is closed. Thx!

Comment: @Shnugo what the diff btw `FOR XML PATH` & `AUTO`? I can only accept the answer with in two days..i will do that..thanks..

Comment: In `ATUO` mode the SQL Server has to decide how to build the structure. In `PATH` mode this is done by you and is interpreted straight forward. You see this, when you try to name a column as attribute not in the first place. SQL Server can rely on you. And: You can do **much much more** with `PATH` (This is a comparison about the features)[http://www.datarelentless.com/2012/4/2/for-xml-raw,-for-xml-explicit,-for-xml-auto-and-for-xml-path.aspx].